# Por que repeti 2 vezes para dar a resposta certar?

Tags: php

Localizar, em um vetor qualquer de valores inteiros, um certo elemento deste, dado o seu valor em php:

```
<?php
 $vet=array(3, 9, 7, 5, 6);
  $chave = 9; // valor que se deseja localizar
$nao_localizado = true;
$candidato = 0; // indice do candidato no vetor

    while ( $nao_localizado && $candidato < $vet){
        if ( $vet[ $candidato ] == $chave ){
        $nao_localizado = false; // localizado o valor
        }else{
        $candidato++; // avanca para o proximo candidatohttp://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help
}
    if ( $nao_localizado ){
        echo( "Nao foi localizado o valor " . $chave );
    }
    else{
        echo( "O valor " . $chave .
                " foi localizado na posicao " . $candidato );
    }
} 
    ?>
```

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor a sua pergunta. A fim de deixar claro o que deseja saber. Se puder adicione um exemplo e os códigos que está usando.

Comment: Esse código está funcionando mais ou menos,  a variável chave no código é 9 como tem no vetor o 9 ele é pra dizer o valor e dizer a posição só que na hora de mostra isso ele tá mostrando 2 mensagens com que não encontra e logo após ele mostra o certo que encontro e diz a posição.

Comment: E se eu tirar da variável chave o valor 9 e colocar outro número que não tem no vetor ele aparece a resposta certa, só que se repetindo e dando erro logo após a resposta

Comment: <?php
 $vet=array(3, 9, 7, 5, 6);
  $chave = 9; // valor que se deseja localizar
$nao_localizado = true;
$candidato = 0; // indice do candidato no vetor

    while ( $nao_localizado && $candidato < $vet){
        if ( $vet[ $candidato ] == $chave ){
        $nao_localizado = false; // localizado o valor
        }else{
        $candidato++;
}
    if ( $nao_localizado ){
        echo( "Nao foi localizado o valor " . $chave );
    }
    else{
        echo( "O valor " . $chave .
                " foi localizado na posicao " . $candidato );
    }
} 
    ?>

Comment: Copie o código que fiz abaixo e execute no seu servidor e me diga se deu para entender ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A busca que você está fazendo, é a cada item do vetor. Ou seja, ele compara o valor de item a item do vetor `$vet` com o valor da variável `$chave` que você está procurando.

Ele está escrevendo pois provavelmente é um código com fins acadêmicos. Na prática, só escreveria quando ACHAR o valor, ou seja, você poderia comentar o `echo` que informa que não encontrou.

Abaixo o seu código de uma forma que acho que vai ficar mais fácil para você entender.

```
$vet = array(3, 9, 7, 5, 6); // lista a procurar
$chave = 9; // valor que se deseja localizar

echo "Procurando por $chave na lista: " . implode(", ", $vet).  "."; 

$nao_localizado = true; // afirma que não achou e nega se achar
$candidato = 0; // indice do candidato no vetor

while ($nao_localizado && $candidato < $vet) { // para cada item da lista
    if ($vet[$candidato] == $chave) { // se achou
        $nao_localizado = false; // localizado o valor
    } 

    // escreve se achou ou não achou o item
echo "<br/>Ciclo $candidato do while: "; // marca o ciclo
    if ($nao_localizado) {
        echo( "Nao foi localizado o valor $chave na posicao $candidato do vetor.");
    } else {
        echo( "O valor $chave foi localizado na posicao $candidato do vetor." );
    }
    $candidato++; // avanca para o proximo candidatohttp://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help
}
```

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Comment: Obg pela sua ajuda!!!

Comment: Resolveu o seu problema? Caso positivo, peço que marque a minha resposta como resposta escolhida e também clique na setinha para cima,  isso vai ajudar com a minha pontuação neste site. Obrigado!